# Display a fullscreen gif on page load and close it when the gif has finished

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-video

I want to write a piece of code that plays my gif in fullscreen as soon as the page loads, then closes it when the gif has finished.

Thanks

Comment: `Jquery` is just a `javascript` library, so you should be able to do anything you want in plain old `javascript` which you can do in `Jquery`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FakeLoader

**[DEMO](http://joaopereirawd.github.io/fakeLoader.js/)**

Just replace the charger with your own image .gif

The question is whether it is necessary to do so. Think of load times and user experience...

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a function that displays your gif and another that hides it.
2. Set an onload event listener on the body tag that executes the display gif function.
3. Set a timeout function when the page loads to execute your hide gif function after x seconds where x is the length of your video + 3 (just to allow for a bit of delay)

   window.onload = function() {
       setTimeout(hidegif(), 10000);
   };

Comment: It would be very helpful if you can provide some details on how your answer helps with the original question.